# PHP doesnt send paragraphs in email?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am making a website where you can send tips to a email but the tip is shown as a whole block and not with paragraphs while the tip is shown with paragraphs at the website?

Here u can see it in the email:
[Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ycf.png)

Here is the php code i use to send the email:

```
if(!is_a($entry, WP_Error) && rgar($entry, '2') == $_GET['email']) {



        $toEmail = $_GET['email'];



        $fromName =  get_option('blogname');

        $fromEmail = get_option('admin_email');

        $to = $toEmail;

        $subject  = 'Hierbij uw eerste tip: '.$recent_posts[0]["post_title"];



        $headers  = "From: ".$fromName." <".$fromEmail.">\r\n";

        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$fromEmail."\r\n";

        if(isset($ccMail) && $ccMail!=""){$headers .= "CC: ".$ccMail."\r\n";}

        if(isset($BccMail) && $BccMail!=""){$headers .= "Bcc: ".$BccMail."\r\n";}

        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP v'.phpversion()."\r\n";

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";

        $message = '<html><body>';

        $message .=

                '<a href="http://inreach.nl" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">

                <img src="http://inreach.nl/wp-content/themes/new_inreach/images/logo-inreach-grey.png" alt="Inreach-name" /></a><br><br>

                Beste '.rgar($entry, 1).',<br><br>

                Hebbes!

                <br><br>

                Jouw leiderschapsontwikkeling is gestart met deze eerste tip voor effectiever leiderschap. Veel succes met het inzetten van de kennis!<br><br>

                <b>'.$recent_posts[0]["post_title"].'</b><br><br>

                <div ><img style="max-width:100%" src="'.$image[0].'" alt="photo"/></div><br><br>

                '.$recent_posts[0]["post_content"].'    <br><br><br><br>

                Wil jij over een specifieke situatie of case een tip?<a href="mailto:info@inreach.nl"> Mail me dan! </a> Binnen twee dagen krijg je een persoonlijke reactie waar je mee verder kan.

                <br><br>

                Weet jij anderen die baat kunnen hebben bij deze tips? Stuur deze mail dan door naar ze! Zij kunnen zich aanmelden door <a href="http://inreach.nl/tips/#subscribeTips" target="_blank">HIER</a> te klikken.

                <br><br>

                Hartelijke groet,

                <br><br>

                Steven Brouwers

                <br><br>

                p.s.: toch afmelden? Dat kan <a href="http://inreach.nl/?remove_eid_tips='.$_GET['send_tip_eid'].'&email='.$_GET['email'].'">HIER</a> ';

        $message .= '</body></html>';



        $sent = wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: It's not PHP who doesn't send paragraphs. You are not putting any paragraphs. Please read about `<p>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think it's not a problem about paragraphs. Assuming `$recent_posts[0]["post_content"]` is a string with `\n` for new lines, you could try to use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Replace:

```
$recent_posts[0]["post_content"]
```

With:

```
nl2br($recent_posts[0]["post_content"])
```

It should work. If not, try to inspect what's in `$recent_posts[0]["post_content"]`.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the following code before wp_mail();

```
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

Answer (score -2):

use table instead of div in your $message.
it will work then